# Can't get the same value in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I can't seem to get the same value in array. The first value just doesn't appear in the output. The code compares the id's and joins the values that match the id.This is my code:

```
<?php
$pic = array ('1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg');
$picid = array('aqua','green','orange');
$size = array('12','24','12');
$sizeid = array ('aqua','green','orange');

$newarray2 = array();

foreach (array_combine($pic, $picid) as $outpic => $outid) {

foreach (array_combine($size, $sizeid) as $outsize => $outsizeid) {

 if ($outid == $outsizeid) {

    $result = "$outpic $outsize";
    $newarray2[]= $result;

} }

$result1 = implode(",", $newarray2);
echo $result1;
$newarray2 = array();
}
?>
```

The desired output I want to get is this:

```
1.jpg 12
2.jpg 24
3.jpg 12
```

But when I run the code I get this:

```
2.jpg 24
3.jpg 12
```

I think the first value is being overwritten somehow, but I don't know the way around this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try using `array_push()`.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I tried that but still got the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple keys on 12, only the last one is used.

In the example below we add an additional layer to the keys, so that the keys can overlap.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($size as $i => $key) {
 $result[] = array($key => $sizeid[$i]);
}
foreach ($result as $value) {
 foreach($value as $outsize => $outsizeid){
  if ($outid == $outsizeid) {
   $result = "$outpic $outsize";
   $newarray2[]= $result;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: yes, but how do I get those values with the multiple keys?

Comment: Use array map, or i'll write you an example in a sec

Comment: please give me an example.

Comment: @AlvinOfori-Adjei Here it is, sorry it took so long, i think there might  be a better way :) this ones a bit confusing IMO

Answer (score 0):

This makes more sense if you consider the result of calling "array_combine".

```
$picCombo = array_combine($pic, $picid);
$picCombo = array(
    '1.jpg' => 'aqua',
    '2.jpg' => 'green',
    '3.jpg' => 'orange',
);
$sizeCombo = array_combine($size, $sizeid);
$sizeCombo = array(
    '12' => 'aqua',
    '24' => 'green',
    '12' => 'orange',
);
```

In PHP, the syntax, in array definitions and foreach statements are:

```
key => value
```

Note that your keys and values are the opposite of what you want. 
So, solutions:

1. array_combine($picid, $pic); // Reverse the arrays
2. Just define the array as I've done above, with $picCombo.

Comment: Obviously, the onus is on you to make sure the IDs in $picId and $sizeId are unique.

Comment: thank you but I don't really get how I should constract the foreach statement